# Is there a way to add a bot in a second tab in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: tabs, microsoft-teams

I have a OpenAI Chatbot which I integrated into Microsoft Teams and now I want to add a second tab in that bot which resembles a second bot.Its basically the same bot but with another Endpoint, which uses documents from the company to create responses.

Is it possible to have a second tab in that first bot? As far as I understand it right, its only possible to only 1 teams bot, as the botId Object in manifest.json can only get 1 object in the array and  the second bot has its own botId in its own manifest.json. Furthermore, you have to use the "static tab" in manifest.json to add a personal tab and to my understanding, this is only possible when you host a website as you have to provide the webiste Url object in "static tab"

Lets assume you are able to add a second bot in a second tab, is it possible to do it, without hosting a webapp to use "static tab" in the manifest?

Here are helpful links for this topic:

Prerequisites
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements

Create a personal tab
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab?tabs=vs&pivots=node-java-script

Manifest Schema
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema

Thank you in advance.

I already tried to use the "contentBotId" object to integrate the bot, but it seems like it was wrong as this object is used to create adaptive tabs and not personal tabls

Comment: Nope, it's not possible to host an actual second Teams bot, as a kind of 2nd "Chat" tab. What could -possibly- work is adding the web in an embedded web experience, using the "web" channel in bot framework, and embedding this inside a static tab. Can you not achieve what you want inside a single bot though? If you really can't, why not just add a second bot app?